# Abort previous ajax request on easy auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, easyautocomplete

I am using a easyAutoComplete plugin. I need to abort previous ajax request on new request.
Here is the link of plugin which I used. 
http://easyautocomplete.com/

and my code is

```
  var options = {
    url: function (phrase) {
        return "api/getData";
    },
    getValue: function (element) {
        return element['name'];
    },
    ajaxSettings: {
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    preparePostData: function (data) {
        data.phrase = $(".name").val();
        return data;
    },
    match: {
        enabled: true
    }
};
$(".name").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to define request delay

---->  requestDelay: 400

 var options = {
    url: function (phrase) {
        return "api/getData";
    },
    getValue: function (element) {
        return element['name'];
    },
    ajaxSettings: {
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    preparePostData: function (data) {
        data.phrase = $(".name").val();
        return data;
    },
    match: {
        enabled: true
    },
  requestDelay: 400
};
$(".name").easyAutocomplete(options);
```